# Getting Exception in thread "main" com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.RhapsodyRuntimeException: Can't co-create object

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, rhapsody, ibm-rational

```
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.IRPApplication;
import com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.RhapsodyAppServer;

public class TestRhapsody {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IRPApplication irpApplication =  RhapsodyAppServer.createRhapsodyApplication();
  }
}
```

I am using windows 10 64bit
JDK 64bit

Issue will not exits in windows 8/7 Only in windows 10 facing this problem.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved after switching to latest Rhapsody version 8.3.1

I have faced this **Can't co-create object** issue in Rhapsody version 8.2.1. After migrating to **Rhapsody version 8.3.1** Issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need everything to be in either 32 bit or 64 bit. 
when i say everything it means

- Rhapsody
- JVM
- Eclipse

If you are trying 64 bit i would encourage to try out the 32 bit. I had problems with 64 bit and switched to 32 bit

Comment: Did you faced the same issue with 64bit ?

Comment: I have tried with 32 bit Rhapsody, JVM and eclipse But Still same problem persisting.

Comment: It looks like you are creating app have you tired getting active app using the command RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication(). This will help us at least know that the set up is working.  Also just checking do you have your Java Build path set to access rhapsody.jar file?

Comment: I have tried to get active application using RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication() . Getting active application without exception.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an bad install, i.e. the Rhapsody installation did not complete and register the DLLs correctly. (Which is why an upgrade was perceived to have fixed the issue). To fix the issue you would need to have admin on the windows machine.

1. Run a command prompt as Administrator (this is important, right-click and Run as Administrator)
2. Browse to where the rhapsody.exe is.
3. Type rhapsody.exe /RegServer
4. Type rhapsody.reg

Note: If you have multiple Rhapsody's installed then the COM API for only one can be registered (usually the last one) and hence you need to re-register (run rhapsody.exe /RegServer as admin) to switch between them. If you don't do this then plugins may get unexpected errors.